# WHERE в подтаблице про значению в основной таблице

Tags: sql

> SELECT DISTINCT name,CAST(SUM(kills) as FLOAT)/(CAST(SUM(deaths) as FLOAT)) as
>   killToDeathRatio FROM MatchesPlayers WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
>   MatchesPlayers WHERE name=name из внешнего запроса)>=10

У меня есть таблица с полем name,kills,deaths. Я хочу выбрать всех пользователей по одному разу и отсортировать по считаемому значению(killToDeathRatio). Но я хочу включать в список только тех, кто в самой таблице встречается более 10 раз.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> SELECT name,CAST(SUM(kills) as FLOAT)/(CAST(SUM(deaths) as FLOAT)) as
>   killToDeathRatio FROM MatchesPlayers  GROUP BY name **HAVING COUNT(*) >=
>   10 AND SUM(deaths)>0** ORDER BY CAST(SUM(kills) as
>   FLOAT)/(CAST(SUM(deaths) as FLOAT)) DESC

HAVING COUNT(*) >=
 10 AND SUM(deaths)>0 - условия которые применимы к большинству таблиц. Взято из ORACLE но работает и на SQL SERVER и думаю много где еще

Comment: Везде работает, это базовый SQL